# Get tree of mbeans attributes values

Tags: java, weblogic

I get mbeans value (weblogic JMS configuration) from server with JMX

And diferrent attributes have different return type as:

```
Ljavax.management.ObjectName;
javax.management.ObjectName
Ljava.lang.String;
```

For each attribute this returns lists of values, I do loop for/if/else in my code.

It's very nested code at end. Is there better way?

```
//JMS modules
public static void getJMSmodulleRuntimes() throws Exception {
    ObjectName domain = getJMSserverRuntimes();

    String DomainName = (String)connection.getAttribute(domain, "Name");

    ObjectName[] JMSModules = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(domain,"JMSSystemResources");

    for (int i = 0; i < JMSModules.length; i++){
        String JMSMonudelsName = (String)connection.getAttribute(JMSModules[i],"Name");

        ObjectName JMSSystemResources = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=" + JMSMonudelsName+",Location="+DomainName+",Type=JMSSystemResource");
        MBeanAttributeInfo[] JMSSystemResourcesBeans = (connection.getMBeanInfo(JMSSystemResources)).getAttributes();
        System.out.println("    -");

        for(MBeanAttributeInfo JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute:JMSSystemResourcesBeans) {

            if (JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName().equals("JMSResource"))
            {
                ObjectName JMSResourceURL = (ObjectName)connection.getAttribute(JMSSystemResources,JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName());

                MBeanAttributeInfo[] JMSResourceParams = (connection.getMBeanInfo(JMSResourceURL)).getAttributes();
                System.out.println("        JMSResourceParams:");

                    for(MBeanAttributeInfo JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute:JMSResourceParams) {
                        if (JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute.getType().equals("[Ljavax.management.ObjectName;"))
                        {
                            ObjectName[] JMSResourceParamsList = (ObjectName[])connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceURL,JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute.getName());
                            if (JMSResourceParamsList.length == 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println("            " + JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute.getName() + ": Null");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("            " + JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute.getName() + ": " );
                                for (int j = 0; j < JMSResourceParamsList.length; j++) {
                                    // String AttributeObject = (String)connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsList[j],"Name");
                                    System.out.println("           - "); // + AttributeObject+":"
                                    MBeanAttributeInfo[]  JMSResourceParamsListObjects = (connection.getMBeanInfo(JMSResourceParamsList[j])).getAttributes();
                                        for(MBeanAttributeInfo JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute:JMSResourceParamsListObjects) {
                                            if (JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName().matches("Password|PasswordEncrypted|JNDIPropertiesCredential")) 
                                            {
                                                System.out.println("                "+JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName()+": (clear or encrypt text)");
                                            }
                                            else if (JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getType().equals("[Ljavax.management.ObjectName;"))
                                            {
                                                ObjectName[] JMSResourceParamsListL2 = (ObjectName[])connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsList[j],JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName());
                                                System.out.println("                " + JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName() + ": " );
                                                //System.out.println("               - ");
                                                for (int k = 0; k < JMSResourceParamsListL2.length; k++) {
                                                    MBeanAttributeInfo[]  JMSResourceParamsListObjectsL2 = (connection.getMBeanInfo(JMSResourceParamsListL2[k])).getAttributes();
                                                    System.out.println("                   - ");    
                                                    for(MBeanAttributeInfo JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttributeL2:JMSResourceParamsListObjectsL2) {
                                                            if (JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttributeL2.getName().matches("Password|PasswordEncrypted|JNDIPropertiesCredential")) 
                                                                System.out.println("                    "+JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttributeL2.getName()+": (clear or encrypt text)");
                                                            else
                                                                System.out.println("                    " + JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttributeL2.getName() + ": " + (connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsListL2[k],JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttributeL2.getName())));
                                                        }

                                                }
                                            }

                                            else if (JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getType().equals("javax.management.ObjectName") && (connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsList[j],JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName())) != null)
                                            {
                                                System.out.println("                " + JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName() + ":");
                                                ObjectName javaxObjectNameURL = (ObjectName)connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsList[j],JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName());
                                                MBeanAttributeInfo[]  javaxObjectNameURLAttributes = (connection.getMBeanInfo(javaxObjectNameURL)).getAttributes();

                                                    for(MBeanAttributeInfo javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo:javaxObjectNameURLAttributes) {

                                                        if (javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo.getName().equals("ErrorDestination") && (connection.getAttribute(javaxObjectNameURL,javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo.getName())) != null)
                                                        {
                                                            ObjectName objnames = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(javaxObjectNameURL,javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo.getName());
                                                            String objname = (String)connection.getAttribute(objnames,"Name");
                                                                System.out.println("                        " + javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo.getName() + ": " + objname);
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                        System.out.println("                        " + javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo.getName() + ": "+(connection.getAttribute(javaxObjectNameURL,javaxObjectNameURLAttributesInfo.getName())));
                                                        }
                                                    }   
                                                // String objname = (String)connection.getAttribute(objnameurl,"Name");

                                            }

                                            else if (JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getType().equals("[Ljava.lang.String;"))
                                            {
                                                String[] tagnames = (String[])connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsList[j],JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName());
                                                if (tagnames.length == 0) {
                                                    System.out.println("                " + JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName()+": Null");
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("                " + JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName()+":");
                                                        for (int p = 0; p < tagnames.length; p++){
                                                            System.out.println("               - " + tagnames[p]);

                                                        }
                                                }   
                                            }

                                            else
                                                System.out.println("                " + JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName()+": " + (connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceParamsList[j],JMSResourceParamsListObjectsAttribute.getName())));

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println("            " + JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute.getName() + ": " + (connection.getAttribute(JMSResourceURL,JMSResourceParamsBeansAttribute.getName())));
                        }   
                    }
            }
            else if (JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getType().equals("[Ljava.lang.String;"))
            {
                String[] tagnames = (String[])connection.getAttribute(JMSSystemResources,JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName());
                if (tagnames.length == 0) {
                    System.out.println("        " + JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName()+": No Data");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("        " + JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName()+":");
                        for (int p = 0; p < tagnames.length; p++){
                            System.out.println("          - " + tagnames[p]);

                        }
                }   
            }
            else if (JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getType().equals("[Ljavax.management.ObjectName;"))
            {
                if (JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName().equals("SubDeployments"))
                {

                    ObjectName[] SubDeploymentsParamList = (ObjectName[])connection.getAttribute(JMSSystemResources,JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName());

                    //System.out.println("               - ");
                    if (SubDeploymentsParamList.length == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("        " + JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName() + ": Null" );
                    }
                    else
                        System.out.println("        " + JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName() + ": " );
                        for (int k = 0; k < SubDeploymentsParamList.length; k++) {
                            MBeanAttributeInfo[]  SubDeploymentsParamListMbeans = (connection.getMBeanInfo(SubDeploymentsParamList[k])).getAttributes();
                            System.out.println("           - ");    
                            for(MBeanAttributeInfo info:SubDeploymentsParamListMbeans) {
                                if (info.getType().equals("[Ljavax.management.ObjectName;"))
                                {
                                    ObjectName[] objnames = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(SubDeploymentsParamList[k],info.getName());
                                    for (int j = 0; j < objnames.length; j++){
                                        String objname = (String)connection.getAttribute(objnames[j],"Name");
                                        System.out.println("            " + info.getName() + ": " + objname);
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (info.getType().equals("[Ljava.lang.String;"))
                                {
                                    String[] tagnames = (String[])connection.getAttribute(SubDeploymentsParamList[k],info.getName());
                                    if (tagnames.length == 0) {
                                        System.out.println("            " + info.getName()+": No Data");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("            " + info.getName()+":");
                                            for (int p = 0; p < tagnames.length; p++){
                                                System.out.println("           - " + tagnames[p]);

                                            }
                                    }   
                                }
                                else
                                System.out.println("            " + info.getName() + ": " + (connection.getAttribute(SubDeploymentsParamList[k],info.getName())));
                            }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ObjectName[] objnames = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(JMSSystemResources,JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName());
                    for (int j = 0; j < objnames.length; j++){
                        String objname = (String)connection.getAttribute(objnames[j],"Name");
                        System.out.println("        " + JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName() + ": " + objname);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName().equals("Parent") || JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName().equals("Resource"))
            {

            }
            else
            System.out.println("        " + JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName() + ": " + (connection.getAttribute(JMSSystemResources,JMSSystemResourcesBeansAttribute.getName())));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it myself. It worked for me

```
public static void parser(String javaxExcept, String LjavaxExcept, HashMap < String, Object > [] atrs, ObjectName ObjUrl, int ng, ObjectName[] origObjUrl) throws Exception {

    if (ng > 20) {
        System.out.println("Possibly loop detected");
        for (int t = 0; t < origObjUrl.length; t++) {
            System.out.println(origObjUrl[t]);
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }

    origObjUrl[ng] = ObjUrl;
    MBeanAttributeInfo[] attributes = (connection.getMBeanInfo(ObjUrl)).getAttributes();
    atrs[ng].put("ObjUrl", ObjUrl.toString());
    for (MBeanAttributeInfo attribute: attributes) {
        if (attribute.getType().equals("[Ljava.lang.String;")) {
            String[] Ljava = (String[]) connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName());
            if (Ljava.length == 0) {
                atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), "null");
            } else {
                for (int p = 0; p < Ljava.length; p++) {
                    atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), Ljava[p]);
                }
            }
        } else if (attribute.getName().matches(".*(Password|KeyStorePass|PassPhrase|JNDIPropertiesCredential|ClearText|EncryptedValue).*")) {
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), "clear or encrypt text");
        } else if (attribute.getType().matches("java.util.Properties")) {
            Map < String, String > propmap = (Map < String, String > ) connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName());
            if (attribute.getName().matches("BootProperties")) {
            propmap.put("password", "{AES} encrypt text");
            propmap.put("username", "{AES} encrypt text"); }
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), propmap);
        } else if (attribute.getType().equals("javax.management.ObjectName") && attribute.getName().matches(javaxExcept) && (connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName())) != null) {
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), (connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName()).toString()));
        } else if (attribute.getType().matches("java.lang.String|java.lang.Integer|java.lang.Boolean")) {
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), (connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName())));
        } else if (attribute.getType().equals("javax.management.ObjectName") && (connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName())) != null) {
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), attribute.getName());
            ng = ng + 1;
            atrs[ng] = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
            ObjUrl = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName());
            parser(javaxExcept, LjavaxExcept, atrs, ObjUrl, ng, origObjUrl);
            atrs[ng - 1].put(attribute.getName(), atrs[ng]);
            ng = ng - 1;
            ObjUrl = origObjUrl[ng];
        } else if (attribute.getType().equals("[Ljavax.management.ObjectName;") && attribute.getName().matches(LjavaxExcept)) {
            ObjectName[] Ljavax = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName());
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), attribute.getName());
            String[] Ljavaxarray = new String[Ljavax.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < Ljavax.length; j++) {
                Ljavaxarray[j] = Ljavax[j].toString();
              }
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), Ljavaxarray);
        } else if (attribute.getType().equals("javax.management.openmbean.ArrayType")) {
            CompositeData[] compdata = (CompositeData[]) connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName());
            String[] kvcompdata = new String[compdata.length];
            int l = 0;
            for (CompositeData kv: compdata) {
                kvcompdata[l] = kv.get("DisplayName").toString();
                l = l + 1;
            }
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), kvcompdata);
        } else if (attribute.getType().equals("[Ljavax.management.ObjectName;")) {
            ObjectName[] Ljavax = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName());
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), attribute.getName());
            HashMap < String, Object > Ljavaxmap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
            for (int j = 0; j < Ljavax.length; j++) {
                ng = ng + 1;
                atrs[ng] = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
                ObjUrl = Ljavax[j];
                parser(javaxExcept, LjavaxExcept, atrs, ObjUrl, ng, origObjUrl);
                boolean success = false;
                String Ljavaxaname = new String();
                try {
                    Ljavaxaname = (connection.getAttribute(Ljavax[j], "Name")).toString();
                    success = true;
                } catch (AttributeNotFoundException e) {}
                if (success) {
                    Ljavaxaname = (connection.getAttribute(Ljavax[j], "Name")).toString();
                } else {
                    Ljavaxaname = (connection.getAttribute(Ljavax[j], "Key")).toString();
                }
                Ljavaxmap.put(Ljavaxaname, atrs[ng]);
                ng = ng - 1;
            }
            atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), Ljavaxmap);
            ObjUrl = origObjUrl[ng];
        } else {
            if (connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName()) == null) {
                atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), "null");
            } else {
                atrs[ng].put(attribute.getName(), (connection.getAttribute(ObjUrl, attribute.getName()).toString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```